Use a server and CA certificate for a server SslStream
My C# application (.NET 8) runs a TCP server that accepts SSL/TLS connections, like from any web browser. (It also implements the HTTP protocol, but that's not relevant here.)
For the browser (or any client) to trust the connection, both the server's and the CA certificate must be sent out by the server. I know how it works from configuring Apache servers. But in C# that seems to be a highly uncommon and problematic task. I was able to cobble together some code with the help of ChatGPT but it's not working and the AI can't fix it, or at least it tends to forget some features with the next iteration.
Here's the part that combines the both certificates into one, because SslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(SslServerAuthenticationOptions) and SslServerAuthenticationOptions.ServerCertificate can only accept a single X509Certificate instance, not a whole X509Certificate2Collection.
string certificateFileName = "hostcert.pem";
string keyFileName = "hostkey.pem";
string caCertificateFileName = "cacert.pem";

var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(certificateFileName, keyFileName);
// Work around https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23749 on Windows:
certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(caCertificateFileName))
{
    var caCertificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(caCertificateFileName));
    //// Work around https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23749 on Windows:
    //caCertificate = new X509Certificate2(caCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));

    // Create a certificate chain
    var certificateChain = new X509Certificate2Collection
    {
        certificate,
        caCertificate   // commenting this out doesn't change the exception
    };

    // Export the collection as a PFX and re-import it as a single X509Certificate2 instance
    byte[] pfxData = certificateChain.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password")!;
    certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxData, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
}

The certificateChain.Export call throws a CryptographicException saysing "Key not valid for use in specified state". Using certificate alone works, but I need to merge it with the caCertificate somehow. How can that be done?
I couldn't even test the last line of the code so I'm not sure if that would work. It seems to be complicated to handle certificates in general, there are hidden flags and states that would allow "exporting" and if not set properly throw exceptions. I don't understand how that works. I just have the three necessary PEM files and need the SslStream class to use them appropriately.

Does your merge certificate look like one at following : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386535&type=1

It's not one file, it's three (see beginning of code), but they look each like the shown format. It's the PEM format.

Try manually creating one file and see if it works.  Then we will know for sure if the issue is with separate files.

"both the server's and the CA certificate must be sent out by the server." that's a myth. The CA certificate should be in the client's trust store anyway, so no need to send it. If the client doesn't trust the CA then nothing you can do from the server side will make a difference, you need to fix the client. You only need to send the intermediate CA certificates. In any case, why are you storing it as a file rather than in the machine certificate store?

Merging your certs into a PFX won't help.  When you open the PFX up again the cert from the PFX won't remember that it came from a PFX, so won't know that's an interesting place to look for the CA certificate.
The CA certificate (when needed) is retrieved automatically by ambient state (cert AIA record and/or the LocalMachine\CA store and/or the CurrentUser\CA store).  If ambient state isn't working for you, and you're on .NET 5+ (not .NET Framework), you can force your CA cert to be considered with
SslStreamCertificateContext ctx = SslStreamCertificateContext.Create(
    serverCertificate,
    [ caCertificate ]);

...

await sslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(
    new SslServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ServerCertificateContext = ctx,
    },
    cancellationToken);

